# Unable to use gdb on Mavericks

Tags: macos

I installed gdb via brew and also [code-signed](https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/BuildingOnDarwin) it. But even after doing that I am getting this error.

```
Error in final launch sequence
Failed to execute MI command:
-exec-run
Error message from debugger back end:
Unable to find Mach task port for process-id 14291: (os/kern) failure (0x5).\n (please check gdb is codesigned - see taskgated(8))
Unable to find Mach task port for process-id 14291: (os/kern) failure (0x5).\n (please check gdb is codesigned - see taskgated(8))
```

Any suggestions as what is going wrong and what I should do?

Comment: I recently ran into this again and was able to make do by prefixing `sudo`, did you try that?

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question. I had to follow the steps [enlisted here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19877047/18852) to get past this error.

1. Creating a **Code-Sign System Certificate** from Keychain Access.
2. Marking that Certificate to *Trust Always*. This is important.
3. Finally code signing the gdb executable `codesign -s gdb-cert /path/to/gdb`

With this, I was able to use gdb on mavericks.

Comment: Did you simply `brew install gdb`? I installed both GCC 4.9 and GDB 7.7.1 on Mavericks via Homebrew, but GDB does not work entirely correctly. I can set breakpoints, but cannot query the values of variables. GDB always reports that it `could not find the frame base` for some functions. Apparently many people also encounter the same problem. Would you please elaborate on how GCC and GDB were installed on your Mac?

Comment: I installed it via brew. I don't remember the steps now, but did not struggle much.

Comment: Thanks. I guess this kind of problem is very hard to resolve.

Comment: I've followed these steps on Yosemite, and it still doesn't work. I can run gdb as root, however.